# I want to know if it is possible to export after a function is activated?

Tags: javascript, module

I have a code in which there is an empty variable of global scope, and I have a function that will take the id of a link that was clicked and after that click the value of the captured id will be passed to the variable that is empty and I need to export of that variable to another script, but when I export and import it in the other script it always goes as undefined. I need help to solve this problem and export this variable with the value of the id.

```
var objetoApiClicado;
var noticias = [];
fetch("https://api-kwi5.onrender.com/v1/api/noticias")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    noticias = data.response;
    console.log(noticias);
    openNoticias(noticias);
  })
  .catch((erro) => {
    console.log(erro)
})
function openNoticias(noticias) {
  const btnNoticiasId = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]');
  btnNoticiasId.forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener("click", event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(e.parentNode);
      idNoticia = e.getAttribute('data-id');
      console.log(idNoticia);
      objetoApiClicado = noticias.find(noticia => noticia.id == idNoticia);
      console.log(objetoApiClicado);  
    });
    
  }); 
}
export {
  idNoticia,
  objetoApiClicado
}
```

Script where I will import the variable:

```
import  {idNoticia , objetoApiClicado}  from "./noticias.js";
var noticia = [ ];
async function verificaId() {
       const conexao = await fetch(`https://api-kwi5.onrender.com/v1/api/noticias`);
       const noticiasResponse = await conexao.json();
       noticia = noticiasResponse.response;
       console.log(noticia)
       let id = idNoticias;
       const comparaId = noticia.find(noticia => noticia.id == parseInt(id));
       console.log(comparaId);
       exibirBanner(comparaId)
       exibirNoticias(comparaId)
  }

function exibirBanner(noticia) { 
   const bannerSection = document.querySelector('.banner__postagem--container');  
           bannerSection.innerHTML += `
           <div class="banner__postagem--conteudo">
               <h2 class="banner__postagem--titulo">${noticia.titulo}</h2>
               <p class="banner__postagem--data">Julho 7, 2023  Notícia</p>
           </div>
           `
   };

function exibirNoticias(noticias) {   
   const noticiaSection = document.querySelector('.postagem__container');
          noticiaSection.innerHTML += `
           <div class="postagem__container--conteudo">
                 <img src="data:image/png;base64,${noticias.file}" alt="Dentista mostrando 4 mitos dos implante dentarios" class="postagem__imagem">
               <p class="postagem__texto">${noticias.conteudo}</p>
               </div>`
}
```

I already tried to export the function with a return at the end of it but I find that when I do the import the whole function comes.

Comment: What do you use the variable for in the other script?

Comment: Please edit your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76767850/i-need-to-export-a-variable-that-is-inside-a-function-to-another-script) instead of deleting and reposting it

Comment: The typical problem is not that the variable does not get exported/imported correctly, but simply that you are accessing it before the button was clicked and the value was assigned. Please show us the code of the other module and explain how (when!) it is supposed to execute.

Comment: @geshode
 I want to use this variable with the id to get a news item with the same id in an api

Comment: Then you could just call a function that does that and give it the variable as a parameter, when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Bergi

I edited the question by adding the script where I'm going to import the variable
So I want that when the user clicks on a link the function openNoticias(); it will take the id of the link that was clicked and then pass this value to the idNoticia variable and then I want to export it to another script where I will query the api for a news item with an id similar to the idNoticia variable and after that I will use the returned data by the api and consumed in the displayBanner() and displayNoticias() functions, which will show this data in the html.

Comment: And where/when is `verificaId()` called? If you want the search to happen whenever the link is clicked, you rather should just **call** `verificaId(…)` that imported from the search script into the the first script. Then you can just pass the `idNoticia` as an argument, you don't need (and shouldn't use) a global variable.

Comment: @Bergi
I just want to confirm if I understood correctly what you asked me to do because I am using a translator, and it tends to translate things in a confusing way. You want me to export the `verificaId( )` function in the first script and then import it into the second script. Then, inside the `openNoticias( )` function, I will use `verificaId(idNoticias)` by passing idNoticias as a parameter. If this is what you asked me to do, the result remains the same; I keep receiving "undefined" in the second script.

Comment: Yes, otherwise  `verificaId` would never get called, would it? If it still doesn't work, make sure the `verificaId` actually uses the parameter not the global variable - remove the imports and exports of `idNoticias`. Oh, and it seems you should do the same for `objetoApiClicado`.

Comment: If you can't get it to work, please [edit] your question to update it with your latest code. Btw, you have a typo, using `idNoticias` instead of `idNoticia`. You should get an exception from that though, not an `undefined` value.